Using NextMethod with internal generics
With a generic that uses UseMethod, NextMethod works as I expect:
f <- function(...) UseMethod("f")
f.default <- function(...) 5
f.foo <- function(...) {print("hi"); NextMethod()}
x <- structure(1, class = "foo")
f(x) # prints "hi", returns 5

With the following internal generic, a similar approach does not work:
# NB: base::cbind is an internal generic
cbind.default <- function(...) 5
cbind.foo <- function(...) {print("hi"); NextMethod()}
cbind(x) # prints "hi", Error in NextMethod() : generic function not specified

Is NextMethod usable with internal generics, and if so, what arguments etc. are needed?

This behaviour stems from bespoke machinery for dispatch on ... in the C-level do_bind (see bind.c).  It does not use the conventional mechanism for dispatch documented in help("NextMethod") and implemented in the C-level Dispatch[Any]OrEval() (see eval.c).  Crucially, method look-up succeeds but the method call is not evaluated in an environment defining the variables .Generic, .Method, .Class, etc. essential for dispatch by NextMethod.
On one hand, it is well documented that the dispatch mechanism used by [cr]bind is exceptional (see section "Dispatch" in help("cbind")).  On the other hand, c is conceptually quite parallel to [cr]bind, also dispatching internally on ..., but c does not have this limitation:
> m <- function(...) { cat("a\n"); NextMethod() }
> for (generic in c("c", "cbind", "rbind")) .S3method(generic, "a", m)
> x <- structure(0, class = "a")
> c(x)
a
[1] 0
> cbind(x)
a
Error in NextMethod() : generic function not specified
> rbind(x)
a
Error in NextMethod() : generic function not specified
> debug(m)
> c(x)
debugging in: c.a(x)
debug at #1: {
    cat("a\n")
    NextMethod()
}
Browse[1]> ls(all.names = TRUE)
[1] "..."             ".Class"          ".Generic"        ".GenericCallEnv"
[5] ".GenericDefEnv"  ".Group"          ".Method"        
Browse[1]> Q
> cbind(x)
debugging in: cbind(deparse.level, ...)
debug at #1: {
    cat("a\n")
    NextMethod()
}
Browse[1]> ls(all.names = TRUE)
[1] "..."
Browse[1]> Q
> rbind(x)
debugging in: rbind(deparse.level, ...)
debug at #1: {
    cat("a\n")
    NextMethod()
}
Browse[1]> ls(all.names = TRUE)
[1] "..."
Browse[1]> Q

It seems quite "wrong" to me that [cr]bind and c should behave differently here.  So I've filed a bug report: https://bugs.r-project.org/show_bug.cgi?id=18779

It looks like for cbind, the ".default" method for the function basically doesn't do anything. It's not defined and doesn't actually get called. So there's no NextMethod to find essentially. You can change the class inside your custom method to get the behavior you want. Here we strip the class and try calling the base cbind again.
cbind.foo <- function(x, ...) {print("hi"); cbind(unclass(x))}
# [1] "hi"
#      [,1]
# [1,]    1

It uses the value of 1 from x and not the value of 5 from cbind.default because that's never called.

as.vector is internal generic (in .internalGenerics) and does not behave in the way that cbind appears to behave.

as.vector.foo <- function(x, mode = "any") { print("foo"); NextMethod() }; as.vector.default <- function(x, mode = "any") { print("default"); x }; as.vector(structure(0, class = "foo"))

Looking at methods(as.vector) it has a as.vector,ANY-method S4 method. So perhaps that's the difference.

So cbind can dispatch to a class-specific method cbind.foo, but does not set up .Generic, .Method, .Class like Mikael said. Thus cbind.foo must be implemented like a normal function, and cannot do inheritance. But inheritance can be kind-of simulated by changing the class of x and recalling cbind(x) within cbind.foo

The difference is that do_asvector in coerce.c uses DispatchOrEval, while do_bind in bind.c uses applyClosure directly, i.e., not constructing a correct evaluation frame for the method call.

Hence it appears to me to be a bug in the C-level do_bind.

Adv-R 13.7.2: "internal generics ... don’t call UseMethod() but instead call the C functions DispatchGroup() or DispatchOrEval()". If this is definitive then calling applyClosure instead of DispatchOrEval could well be a bug

On the other hand, because cbind and rbind dispatch on ... rather than x, it's understandable that they do things differently.  In fact, help("cbind") documents clearly that dispatch in these cases is really exceptional.  I'll still write a bug report, mainly because c, which also dispatches on ..., does not have this problem.
